# My meme command doesn't work (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

My Reddit meme command doesn't work. I want my bot to reply with a meme when I say `&meme`, however it doesn't reply and instead gives a runtime error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py:81: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SubredditHelper.__call__' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

The code is:

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
  reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(client_id = "redditclientid", client_secret = "redditsecret", username = "redditusername", password = "redditpassword", user_agent = "chrome")

  subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
  all_subs = []

  top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

  for submission in top:
    all_subs.append(submission)

  random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

  name = random_sub.title
  url = random_sub.url

  em = discord.Embed(title = name)
  em.add_field(url = url)

  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Could you please help me find the error?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I think you don't need `for submission in top: all_subs.append(submission)` because it may only copy values from one list to another and if you use `top` instead  of `all_subs`  in `random.choice(top)` then you should get the same result.

Comment: error s how something about `async` and function `asyncpraw` has word `async`  in name - so maybe it need to use `await` - `reddit = await asyncpraw.Reddit(...)` or maybe `top = await subreddit.top(limit = 50)`

Comment: or maybe you need this `for`-loop but with `async` - like `asyn for ... in ...: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asyncpraw` needs `async` and `await` in some places.

Documentation shows examples with `async` in `for`-loop

```
async for submission in top:
    all_subs.append(submission)
```

You need also `await` in

```
subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes")
```

---

Other problem is `url=` in `add_field`. It can use only `name=`, `value=`, `inline=`. See dooc: [Embed.add_field](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field)

If you want to display image then you need `set_image`

```
 em.set_image(url=url)
```

With `add_field` you may add it as link in text using string with `[Some text](your url)`

```
 em.add_field(name="My Field", value=f"[Click me]({url})")
```

Eventually you may add link in title directly in `Embed`

```
 em = discord.Embed(title=name, url=url)
```

---

And here screenshot with all three versions: `set_image`, `add_field` and `Embed`

[image]

---

Minimal working code:

I don't use information about my account on reddit so I don't need `username` and `password`

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncpraw
import random

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

REDDIT_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('REDDIT_CLIENT_ID')
REDDIT_SECRET    = os.getenv('REDDIT_SECRET')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="&")

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    print("Connected as", client.user.name)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready as", client.user.name)

@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):

    #searching_msg = await ctx.send("Searching ...")
    
    # https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API    
    # https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example#first-steps
    # https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html#using-an-http-or-https-proxy-with-async-praw
    
    reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(
        client_id=REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=REDDIT_SECRET,
        user_agent="linux:pl.furas.blog:v0.1 (by/furas_freeman)",
    )

    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes")  # await

    top = subreddit.top(limit=50)
    
    all_subs = [item async for item in top]

    #all_subs = []
    
    #async for submission in top:   # async
    #    all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    #await searching_msg.delete()  # remove message `Searching ...`
    #await ctx.message.delete()    # remove user message with `&meme`
    
    # --- display as image ---
    
    em = discord.Embed(title=name)
    em.set_image(url=url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)        

    # --- display as link in text ---

    em = discord.Embed(title=name)
    em.add_field(name="My Field", value=f"[Click me]({url})")
    await ctx.send(embed=em)        

    # --- display as link in title ---

    em = discord.Embed(title=name, url=url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)        

    # ---
        
    await reddit.close()
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Although it doesn't throw up the error now, the command doesn't work. Here's the code: https://replit.com/@kooldamian28/openbot

Comment: I was building minimal bot to test it but I'm busy at this moment. I can only sugest to use `print()` to see values in variables - maybe there is other problem with data.

Comment: I add minimal working code. You have mistake in `add_field`